# can proxy servers be able to maximize performances?

Tags: networking, proxy, proxy-server

it has something to do with optimization performance capability and I don't even understand what this means

I tried searching the answers online but i cant seem to find anything

Answer (score 0):

Yes, proxy servers can maximize performance by caching common/slow some pages and serving up these pages faster.